# How to run a Java HelloWorld program?

Tags: java

I have run into an error. I think my code is right. here it is... please tell me what I have done wrong!!!

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }

}
```

The error I keep getting is...

> Error: Could not find or load main class javatest.java

Comment: Did you change the classname to `HelloWorld`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file name of the Java Class file must be the same one as your Class.

Class: `public class HelloWorld {}`

File: `HelloWorld.java`

Answer (score 0):

The code seems right. Perhaps the issue in how you run it.

The convention is to keep the file name and the public class name as the same. 
When compiling, use `javac <filename>.java`. Then to run simply use `java <classname>`. So, you would use `java HelloWorld`, HelloWorld being the class that contains the main method.